# exporting access query to text file line feed

Tags: sql, ms-access, linefeed, export-to-text

I am creating a sql query for an access database that will be exported to a text file. The requirements include a line feed separating each line. Does that happen by default, or its something that I need to add in? 
If I need to add it, how do I do that?

TIA

Comment: How are you writing to the text file? Can you post code?

Comment: Do you mean linefeed only, or must include linefeed?

Answer (score 1):

TransferText includes LineFeed and I am fairly sure most methods of getting text out of Access will include linefeed, unless you do something to stop it. It is not too difficult to check.

```
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject

s = "c:\docs\test.txt"
DoCmd.TransferText acExportDelim, , "query6", s
Set f = fs.OpenTextFile(s)
a = f.ReadAll

''Split at linefeed: Chr(10)
aa = Split(a, Chr(10))

''Test 1
Debug.Print UBound(aa)

''Test 2
For Each itm In aa
    Debug.Print itm
Next
```

Comment: Actually, it's Cr/Lf, not just Lf, because that's the standard for line termination on Windows. I kind of assumed that since the question asked for Lf only that the target system was not Windows (can't remember whether it's Mac or Linux that uses Lf only).